# Magento custom user inputs on product page

Tags: php, magento

I am looking for some advice or information on how to do the following.  Basically I want to allow users on the product view page to be able to select from a hard-coded custom dropdown menu and when they press 'add to cart' it saves this information to the cart associated with that product.  The drop down menu isn't customisable in the admin section as it is hard-coded in the product page template.

I'm really lost on how to do this or what terms to search for allow me to research this.

Essentially what I'm asking is how do you add custom inputs for each product.

Any help or advice or links would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "how do you add custom inputs for each product" By using an appropriate extension that does so. Or you could copy a custom option from product to another: http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Coping-the-custom-options-to-all-the-products-2027.php In either case, Magento's custom product options are what you should use.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, like someone commented, Custom Options is what you're looking for.

In the admin section for a product you'll find Custom Options as tab. There you want to add a new option with type "Drop-down" and add your values there.

Why would you want to have the options hard coded? Seems like an odd requirement. With Custom Options you have full control to change the options without changing any code.